# Python discord.py Installation

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I have just installed python on my mac for the first time and am trying to make a discord bot, but when I run the command:

`pip install discord.py`

it displays This error:

> [image: This error]

Can anyone please help me? Thanks ~Jake

Comment: exit out of the python interpreter (type `exit()` or `Ctrl-D`) and run that same command in your terminal.

Comment: I would also like to add that I am using the latest version of python as of August 1st 2018.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `pip install discord.py` failed, you should try getting pip in the first place: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

Securely download and run that script, then try all the other answers.

Answer (score 5):

Try using pip install in your terminal, but outside of the python repl.

```
$ pip install discord.py
```

Instead of

```
$ python
>>> pip install discord.py
```

Pip is a program seperate from Python, but it helps install the dependencies for Python.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go into terminal (open a fresh window - DO NOT type python first)
2. Type `pip install dicord.py`
3. Enter